# Generating wordlist with no duplicate and all lower- or upper-case

Tags: dictionary, word-list

How can I generate a wordlist like below:

```
1 specific size, say 10 char
2 lower- and upper- cases
3 number & special chars
4 no duplicate chars in the list
5 no all lowers- or all uppers-
```

I tried crunch but not sure how to get it to do all 5 above.

Here's what I have tried with crunch:

```
# cat 1-charset.lst 
set1 = [abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789+]
./crunch 11 11 -f 1-charset.lst set1 -o list1.txt
```

This starts generating the words as:

```
aaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaab
aaaaaaaaaac
...
...
```

But I'd like it to not have ALL the lower cases or upper cases or any duplicates (aaaaa..).

Comment: Writing code would be a good start. We are not here to do your job for you. Show what you've attempted, and we'll (maybe) try help fixing it.

Comment: Edited the post to add what I tried with crunch.